# English grammar- Preposition

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should be used after the adjective 'nice'?
It is nice (of/for) you to share some motivational tips with your students.

Comment: *Of* and *for* are **after** "nice", not before it. Which is correct depends on what you want the sentence to mean: the meaning changes dramatically with the preposition. Please see the [help page on Prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/prepositions/info) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

**It is nice of you** means you are showing gratitude to that person. You are thankful to the person who gave the lecture.

**It is nice for you** means you are telling the person that they have done something good for themselves.

There is no rule of prepositions to use with nice. It just depends on the syntax.

Comment: It is nice for you....sounds odd to me.